# Should the "differences" and "word choice" tags be made tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I can't really tell which tag to use over the other. Even the tag descriptions seem almost identical:

> **Word-choice**: The differences between two or more words or phrases and how to select the best one for a given situation.
>   **Differences**: Topics related to differences in meaning between two words.

Is there a difference between these two tags? If not, should they be made synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with making them a synonym, but I think [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) should remain the dominant tag, especially since it is used almost five times more often than [differences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences).

In response to [Ataraxia's comment](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/should-the-differences-and-word-choice-tags-be-made-tag-synonyms#comment2666_1055), [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) also can apply to sets of words like phrases (i.e., a choice of words) - it even says so in the excerpt and has been used that way.  (Or, I guess you can take the English site's approach and use a [phrases tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) for those questions.)

[differences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences), on the other hand, seems really broad.  For example, will this tag include differences between verb conjugations, or would the [verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs) and [conjugations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugations) tags be more appropriate?  Does the word "differences" appropriately convey meaningful information about the topic?

Also, [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) is a top 10 tag on all the other language sites like [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choix-de-mot), [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)<sup>1</sup>, [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seleccion-de-palabras), [Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), and [Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0).  I know we set our own rules, but it may be worthwhile to take into account some level of consistency.

<sup>1: German also has a [differences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) tag, but most of the other sites do not.</sup>

Comment: In that case, I agree that word-choice should be the one we go with. Good points.

Comment: Okay, I've made [tag:differences] into a synonym of [tag:word-choice]!

Comment: @snailboat Thanks!